Prove that number $(4n-1)(2n-1)(2n+1)(4n+1)$ is not a perfect square.
the problem
Prove that whatever $n$, a non-zero natural number, the number $(4n-1)(2n-1)(2n+1)(4n+1)$ is not a perfect square.
my idea
I tried working with modular arithmetic in congruences modulo 4, but got to the fact that  $(4n-1)(2n-1)(2n+1)(4n+1)$ is congruent 1 modulo 4 which can make it a perfect square.
However i think the solution can be demonstrated by using modular arithmetic... hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

If you multiply it out, the leading term is $64n^4=(8n^2)^2$.  Can you justify that your expression is greater than $(8n^2-1)^2$?  I haven't tried but think it works.

Your expression is $(16n^2-1)(4n^2-1)$  The gcd of those two factors can only be a power of $3$ (why?) and indeed it appears be either $1$ or $3$ (should be easy to prove that).  Seems relevant.

@RossMillikan i tried it...sadly it doesnt work

@lulu Thanks for your idea. I understand what you mean, but how is this going to help?

The problem with trying modular arithmetic is that with $n=0$, the expression is equal to $1$. So whatever modulus $p$ you try, you'll find $n\equiv 0$ gives you $1$, which is always a quadratic residue.

Other than (possibly) factors of $3^k$, both terms must be perfect squares separately.

Here is a solution not using modular arithmetic.
Let $$m:=4n^2-1.$$ Then, $$(4n-1)(2n-1)(2n+1)(4n+1)=4m^2+3m$$
is not a perfect square, since it stands strictly between $(2m)^2$ and $(2m+1)^2$.

Anne Bauval's answer is perfect, but just to expand on Lulu's comment: the expression is equal to $ab$, where
$$a=16n^2-1,\quad b=4n^2-1$$
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, the only way their product can be a square is if both $a$ and $b$ are squares; but it's not possible for either expression to be a square.
So $a$ and $b$ have to share a factor. Now,
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-4b,b)=\gcd(3,b)\in\{1,3\}$$
We've already looked at the case when they're coprime, so now we need
$$a=3x^2,\quad b=3y^2$$
for some coprime $x$ and $y$.
There are solutions to $4n^2-1=3y^2$ (eg $(n,y)=(1,1)$, or $(n,y)=(13,15)$). But you can use modular arithmetic to check that no solutions exist to $16n^2-1=3x^2$ (since $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $16$).

Here's a modular arithmetic approach.
Since $4n-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$ is never a square, it has some prime factor(s) with odd multiplicity. In order for the final product to be a square, any such factor must divide some other term. But the only term that can have a common factor with $4n-1$ is $2n+1$, which can only have a common factor of $3$ (since $2(2n+1)-(4n-1)=3$; similar calculations give a hcf of at most $2$ for the other options, and $4n-1$ is odd). Therefore $3\mid 4n-1$.
Now $4n+1\equiv 2\pmod 3$ is not a square, so it must have a common factor with something else. But it can't, since it is not a multiple of $3$ (or $2$).
